# firebase with react: signInWithEmailAndPassword does not seem to fail nor succeed

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have a react app in which I'm trying to implement firebase authentication.
registering seems to be fine: registered users show up in my firebase console.
But I'm having trouble getting logging in to work.

I have a firebase.tsx file with, among other code, the following functions:

```
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firebase-firestore";

const config = {
//removed for privacy reasons
};

class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(config);
  }

 login(email: any, password: any) {
    console.log("login function called");
    return app
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("signInWithEmailAndPassword succes");
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  logout() {
    return app.auth().signOut();
  }

  async register(name: any, email: any, password: any) {
    await app.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    //@ts-ignore
    return app.auth().currentUser.updateProfile({
      displayName: name
    });
  }

  getCurrentUsername() {
    console.log(app.auth().currentUser);
    //@ts-ignore
    return app.auth().currentUser.displayName;
  }

isInitialized() {
    console.log("is initialized is called in firebase.tsx");
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      app.auth().onAuthStateChanged(resolve);
    }).then(() => {
      console.log("onauthstatechange resolved");
    });
  }

}

export default new Firebase();
```

in my app.tsx file I have, among other code, this:

```
const [firebaseInitialized, setFirebaseInitialized] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.isInitialized().then((val: any) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(val));
      setFirebaseInitialized(val);
    });
  }, [firebaseInitialized]);
```

when I press the login button in my app, the login function from firebase.tsx is called because the console says "login function called". "signInWithEmailAndPassword succes" does not show up in the console, but remarkably neither does the error message from .catch(unless I log in with false credentials).
So something is probably going wrong with that part but I don't understand why or how.
What does happen is that the entered username and password show up in my browser url.
"is initialized is called in firebase.tsx" and
"onauthstatechange resolved" are also shown in the console.

So these are the things that are logged:

- "login function called";
- "is initialized is called in firebase.tsx"
- "onauthstatechange resolved"
- "undefined"

the undefined log comes from `console.log(JSON.stringify(val));` in the useEffect hook.
using an incognito browser makes no difference

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `onAuthStateChange` callback gets a parameter that indicates the auth state, so you'll want to log that: `}).then((user) => { console.log(user); ...`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your suggestion logs 'null' as well in my case. So that's a problem but I don't understand why that could be the case

Comment: It looks like your `signInWithEmailAndPassword` is not making it to the server, or not getting an answer back. I'm not sure how to debug HTTP calls in React Native, but I'd recommend having a look at that to see if they show any hint as to what's going wrong.

Comment: I'll look into that thnx

Comment: I decided to give this another look and I discovered that during a sign in, the verifypassword request has a status of cancelled...
saw this in my network tab. No idea why that happens though, googling it hasn't given me much results yet.